# How to export data in csv file from hdfs to mysql?

Tags: sqoop

Is it possible to export csv file data  from hdfs to mysql directly or any other approach is available, can u please give me clarity for this.if any other approach is available give me sample code

Answer (score 2):

This can be very easily achieved with [Apache Sqoop](http://sqoop.apache.org/). I would suggest you start with the [export chapter](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.4/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_export_literal) in User Guide.

Answer (score 1):

```
bin/sqoop export \
  --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/hadoop \
  --username dbuser \
  --export-dir hdfs/dir/path \
  --table <db_table>
```

and if the data is tab seperated:

```
bin/sqoop export \
  --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/hadoop \
  --username dbuser \
  --export-dir hdfs/dir/path \
  --table <db_table> \
  --fields-terminated-by '\t'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this from oozie here is a workflow that I call using sub-workflow:

```
<workflow-app name="export_to_db" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.3">
<start to="init-table"/>

<action name="init-table">
    <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>

        <arg>eval</arg>

        <arg>--driver</arg>
        <arg>${jdbcDriver}</arg>

        <arg>--connect</arg>
        <arg>${jdbcUrl}</arg>
        <arg>--username</arg>
        <arg>${dbUser}</arg>
        <arg>--password</arg>
        <arg>${dbPassword}</arg>

        <arg>--query</arg>
        <arg>${createTableSql}</arg>
    </sqoop>

    <ok to="export2db"/>
    <error to="kill"/>
</action>

<action name="export2db">
    <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>

        <arg>export</arg>

        <arg>-Dsqoop.export.statements.per.transaction=${export_statementsPerTransaction}</arg>
        <arg>-Dsqoop.export.records.per.statement=${export_recordsPerBatch}</arg>

        <arg>--driver</arg>
        <arg>${jdbcDriver}</arg>

        <arg>--batch</arg>

        <arg>--num-mappers</arg>
        <arg>${export_numMappers}</arg>

        <arg>--connect</arg>
        <arg>${jdbcUrl}</arg>
        <arg>--username</arg>
        <arg>${dbUser}</arg>
        <arg>--password</arg>
        <arg>${dbPassword}</arg>

        <arg>--input-fields-terminated-by</arg>
        <arg>${export_inputFieldsTerminatedBy}</arg>

        <arg>--export-dir</arg>
        <arg>${exportDir}</arg>

        <arg>--table</arg>
        <arg>${destinationTable}</arg>
    </sqoop>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="kill"/>
</action>

<kill name="kill">
    <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>

<end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```